# Trying to send an email via an office365 account in windows service C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, office365

So im trying to make a simple console app to send emails a few times a day,  im able to make this work when using a gmail account as the sending account but when i try and use my office 365 account it doesnt work, ive tried both port 25 & 587 and i get nothing.

when sending from gmail and port 465 i get
Start sending email over SSL...
email was sent successfully!
Press any key to continue . . .

but with my office account i get this -
Start sending email over SSL...
failed to send email with the following error:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Press any key to continue . . .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EASendMail;       

amespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

try
            {
                SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
                SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.office365.com");

                oServer.User = "user@****.org;
                oServer.Password = "**********";
                oServer.Port = 587;
                oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;
                SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();

                oMail.From = "user@****.org";
                oMail.To = "user@gmail.com";
                oMail.Subject = "test E-Mail Notifications";
                //oMail.TextBody = "this is a test email sent from c# project.";
                oMail.TextBody =  "this is a test email sent from c# project.";
                Console.WriteLine("Start sending email over SSL...");




                // add this line here to generate log file
                oSmtp.LogFileName = "c:\\smtp.txt";
                oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
                Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");

            }
catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: MIssing _oSmtp.EnableSsl = true;_

Comment: does the    oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto; not cover enabling the SSL as true?

Comment: could it be an issue with having DUO dual auth on that account?